# How I can access a JSON value when the key has dot inside its name (in oracle)?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle12c

How I can get value for the "b.c" key? I need to extract that 2 in an efficient way.
I just get null

```
select  js,
        json_value(js,'$.a')  a_value, -- work correctly and give 1
        json_value(js,'$.b.c') b_c_value, -- doesn't work and give null
        json_query(js,'$.b.c') b_c_query  -- I saw this solution somwhere but this also give null
from (select '{"a": "1","b.c": "2"}' js from dual)  -- sample JSON
```

Comment: `json_value(js,'$."b.c"')`.

Comment: Great. thank you. please post it so I can accept it

Answer (score 3):

Put the key in double quotes.  So,

```
json_value(js,'$."b.c"') b_c_value
```

Full example:

```
select  js,
        json_value(js,'$."b.c"') b_c_value
from (select '{"a": "1","b.c": "2"}' js from dual)  -- sample JSON
```

> ```
> +-----------------------+-----------+
> |          JS           | B_C_VALUE |
> +-----------------------+-----------+
> | {"a": "1","b.c": "2"} |         2 |
> +-----------------------+-----------+
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using [`JSON_TABLE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973) function introduced in DB version 12.1.0.2:

```
WITH t(js) AS
(
 SELECT '{"a": "1","b.c": "2"}' FROM dual
)
SELECT a_value, b_c_value
  FROM t
 CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(js, '$'
                           COLUMNS ( 
                                     a_value   INT PATH '$.a',
                                     b_c_value INT PATH '$."b.c"' ) )

A_VALUE B_C_VALUE
------- ---------
      1         2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=44a6a5129349c9f44a1b7d88563ec354)</kbd>